# 'text'=series[string] to const string

Tags: text, pine-script

I am trying to list the number of bullish or bearish candles in a row, for this I use plotshape and I keep a counter to count them, but I have a problem when writing the value

```
c = 1
if bull and bull[1]
    c := c + 1

plotshape(bull, style=shape.triangledown, location=location.abovebar, color=color.green, text = tostring(c))
```

How can I convert `'text'=series[string]` to const string.

I found the function `label.new(...)` but I am looking for something to have over the whole sequence and the labels only appear in the last section of candles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with `label.new()`, try this approach:

```
if bull
    label.new(bar_index, high, text=tostring(c), style=label.style_label_down)
```

Comment: I know the label.new () function exists but the amount of labels I can put with it doesn't seem to be enough, I'm looking to do something like this: https://s3.tradingview.com/snapshots/1/1g4HIrMy.png

Comment: You can pass an argument in the `sturdy("My Script, ...., max_labels_count = 500)`, 500 is the max number of labels you can have, I think this should be enough